# How to use the scrollIntoView in JavaScript with multilple elements?

Tags: javascript, js-scrollintoview

I have some boxes that lot of information. If the user click the button, the box will go to center of the body.

The code is working properly but I want to make the code on JQuery to make it short. Then the boxes above is 3 only, however if I use more than 10 boxes, there's a lot of code.
Can you help me how to make the code in JQuery and how to make the code shorter?

```js
var a = document.getElementsByClassName("indicator");

var b = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");

b[0].addEventListener("click", function() {

  a[0].scrollIntoView({
    behavior: "smooth",
    block: "start"
  });

});

b[1].addEventListener("click", function() {

  a[1].scrollIntoView({
    behavior: "smooth",
    block: "start"
  });

});

b[2].addEventListener("click", function() {

  a[2].scrollIntoView({
    behavior: "smooth",
    block: "start"
  });

});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

h1,
p {
  color: white;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.box {
  margin: 10px;
  background: red;
}

.indicator {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -220px;
  color: red;
  opacity: 0;
}

.btn {
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 6px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

  <div class="box">

    <h1 class="Title"><span class="indicator">.</span>Hello World</h1>

    <p>Stack Overflow is a question-and-answer website for programmers. It is the flagship site of the Stack Exchange Network. It was created in 2008 by Jeff Atwood and Joel Spolsky. It features questions and answers on certain computer programming topics.bFounded
      in 2008 by Joel Spolsky and Jeff Atwood, two developers who wanted to make coding resources more accessible for all. Prosus acquired Stack Overflow for $1.8B in August 2021 , adding the company to their robust education technology portfolio.</p>

    <button class="btn">Scroll Into View</button>

  </div>

  <div class="box">

    <h1 class="Title"><span class="indicator">.</span>Hello World</h1>

    <p>Stack Overflow is a question-and-answer website for programmers. It is the flagship site of the Stack Exchange Network. It was created in 2008 by Jeff Atwood and Joel Spolsky. It features questions and answers on certain computer programming topics.bFounded
      in 2008 by Joel Spolsky and Jeff Atwood, two developers who wanted to make coding resources more accessible for all. Prosus acquired Stack Overflow for $1.8B in August 2021 , adding the company to their robust education technology portfolio.</p>

    <button class="btn">Scroll Into View</button>

  </div>

  <div class="box">

    <h1 class="Title"><span class="indicator">.</span>Hello World</h1>

    <p>Stack Overflow is a question-and-answer website for programmers. It is the flagship site of the Stack Exchange Network. It was created in 2008 by Jeff Atwood and Joel Spolsky. It features questions and answers on certain computer programming topics.bFounded
      in 2008 by Joel Spolsky and Jeff Atwood, two developers who wanted to make coding resources more accessible for all. Prosus acquired Stack Overflow for $1.8B in August 2021 , adding the company to their robust education technology portfolio.</p>

    <button class="btn">Scroll Into View</button>

  </div>

  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

</div>
```

Comment: Hello everyone, can you edit my post and can you add a Code Snippet? Because I dont know how to do it

Comment: What does this have to do with jquery? You're using the plain JS [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) function (which is good, because that's not something you should need jquery or a plugin for).

Comment: As for creating a runnable snippet, there's a dedicated button for it in the [edit] view. If you don't see that button, all it does is give you a convenient UI for creating a text post, so see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/740553 for how you can just write that text yourself if the UI doesn't work. But also remember to reduce your code to [mcve] form. It looks like way too much code to all be necessary for reproducing the problem right now.

Comment: I clicked [edit], then the `[<>]` shaped button. Also your style tags belongs inside the head tags of the document. The script too, but then you need to wrap in `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => { /* Your code */ });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make this code scalable, you could instead listen to the click event on the parent, and traverse the DOM relative to the clicked button:

```
var wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');

wrapper.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation(); // optional, to make the click stop as we will have  processed it
  
  var clickedButton = e.target;
  var elToScrollTo = clickedButton.closest('.box').querySelector('.indicator');

  elToScrollTo.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start' });
});
```

As you see the code got slimmed down significantly. Since the event listener is now attached to just a single element, it's much easier to `.removeEventListener()` (which you should always do to prevent memory leaks - but that's another story).

Comment: @BeAlwaysMine You're welcome. If you accept the answer, you click on the checkbox icon next to it :) That's how StackOverflow works. Also, in StackOverflow the fence syntax (3 ticks) doesn't really work well. It's best to use the `{}` icon - which indents the selected text with 4 spaces. And this works much better.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using code fences and it is often simpler.

Comment: The `[<>]` Snippet editor is the best if the snippet can run

Comment: Also use `let clickedButton = e.target.closest('button');` to handle child elements